# Conditional Allow Contacts to create or add a new case

Tags: civicase, dashboard, user-dashboard, drupal-9

CiviCRM Noob here...

I have the requirement to allow for contacts/individuals to file a request for benefit.
I have a case and timeline created. My question is how does the contact initiate the case process? Specifically, only contacts/individuals of a specific smart group, to have that ability?

Not Antonymous. Contacts-CMS Authenticated users, based on a tag, or a group, more specifically, users without a tag.?.? Or apprea on the contact dashboard..?

Drupal 9
Civi 5.55

Thanks for any help and direction with this.
I have CiviCRM entity installed, thinking rule based module display might do the trick but.. not as straight forward as I thought. No menu item available to create a link. so I am kinda lost

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webform-civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) if you need anonymous users to create cases.

Comment: Not Antonymous. Authenticated users, based on a tag, or a group, more specifically, users without a tag

Comment: If they're authenticated, then you would just use drupal roles and permissions. You can sync with https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_group_roles